# jpg images are not displayed on safari pc / iphone

Tags: javascript, html, image, safari

my website including jpg´s is displayed correctly on IE,FF & Chrome.
Safari on PC and iphone does not display all images. 
If i clear safari cache and load page again the other images are not displayed as before.
I cant find any repeating mechanism which images are displayed or possibly not.

If you open the missing image in a new tab, then the image is correctly displayed. That works in all cases.

http://digikamera.yweb.at/public/uploads/image.php?width=178&image=/public/uploads/Canon-EF-100mm-f-2.8-USM-Macro-Lens-340x225.jpg

I already tired to add missing height definition of images and alt tags. But that did not help. Debugger does not show errors. Whats wrong in my code?

PLease check the issue on:
http://digikamera.yweb.at/Dslr

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: It seems like you missed the `/>` on a lot of your tags in the html. This may or may not be causing some of your issues. Here is the [w3 Validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdigikamera.yweb.at%2FDslr&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They show up fine when I test it in Safari.

However, there are a lot you can do in the XHTML markup to make it more likely to work in different browsers. For example, you are mixing HTML and XHTML, you are using duplicate id:s, you use `height` on tables and table cells.

The W3C validation service found 482 errors in the markup. Plenty of them are of course duplicates, but it's still a lot: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdigikamera.yweb.at%2FDslr&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1):

Code was fixed but the problem was still not solved. I found out that the issue was in the image resize script.

Answer (score 0):

Safari Wierdness: 340k jpg wasn't displaying, even after clicking the refresh icon. However, if I click in the URL box and then hit ENTER, voila! The jpg displays. But still not when using the refresh button.
iPad Wierdness: If I clear the cache and hit enter after putting in the URL, jpg displays. However, even if jpg is displaying, when I click on the refresh icon, the jpg doesn't display in the reloaded page, although I see by the progress bar in the URL box that it was trying.
So, I placed the jpg into a new file with nothing else and it loads normally, even with the refresh button.
Something in my code is preventing proper caching. I'll figure it out.

24 HOURS LATER: Turns out, I had changed the url reference pointing to the jquery file and didn't put the jquery file in that folder. Sure hopes this helps someone else!